# What is a SSH channel, is it an application side logic construct?

Tags: ssh

I understand that SSH is a protocol that runs inside of TCP but one thing I do not understand about the SSH protocol is that it creates a channels. So my question is this, is the channel that ssh creates an application side construct that maps to a thread or process? What is a channel exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Channels in **ssh** are a way to multiplex the TCP/IP connection. You can do with them everything you can do with a TCP connection. Some standard applications are:

- a (pseudo-)terminal session,
- X forwarding,
- port forwarding,
- **sftp**,
- [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs).

They are similar to `HTTP/2` streams.